# Intercept iOS Deep Links

Tags: ios, intercept

I am new to iOS Development and am working on an app concept for a customer. The user experience could be greatly improved if the app was able to intercept a deep link.

This is possible in android since links are not bound to the website but to the app manifest itself. So if I make an app that can receive Amazon links, then the user can choose which app opens those links.

Is this possible on iOS using Apple deep links? I am aware they are more complicated since they require a component on the website itself. Furthermore, the app won't need to receive Amazon links if the Amazon app is installed.

I would attempt this myself but do not have an Apple Developer Account yet and don't want to invest without knowing the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only universal (deep) links you are able to hear about are those directed to your own domain. You cannot receive an Amazon link, because (unless you are Jeff Bezos in disguise) you don't own the amazon.com domain.